# Replication Modes Definitions?

Tags: database, couchdb, replication, distributed-computing

I am currently examining different NoSQL and RDBMSes regarding their replication abilities in order to build distributed systems.

Reading through several papers and books, I get the feeling, that some vendors or authors use their own definitions regarding the terms

- Master-Master Replication (Replication between two servers)
- Master-Slave Replication (Replication between mutliple Servers in order to increase reading speed, writes are only able for the master server)
- Multi-Master Replication (= Peer-To-Peer?)
- Peer-To-Peer Replication (replication between n nodes, each can read/write)
- Merge Replication (?)

E.g: Some mix up the terms Master-Master and Peer-to-Peer as the same, while in Mysql docus for instance I found it is differentiated between Master-Master and Multi-Master (=Peer-to-peer???) Replication.

Where is the difference in Multi-Master and Peer-to-Peer replication?
Is Multi-Master replication's use case more oriented towards Clustering while Peer-To-Peer targets distributed content to distributed applications?

I would like to sort things out and be sure that I have the right understanding in these terms, so maybe a discussion in here would help to merge some knowledge.

Regards, Chris

Edit: added merge replication to the list and some explanations as I understand them...

Comment: Not confident enough to make a proper answer, but I would expect either (1) nobody agrees on the words and people use the terms arbitrarily and incompatibly; or (2) academics agree on the words, and people in the software industry use the terms arbitrarily and incompatibly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding CouchDB, the story is simple. Here it is:

There is only **one** replication mode for CouchDB. The source copies all its data to the target, subject to an optional yes/no filter. I described [CouchDB replication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766391/what-is-the-couchdb-replication-protocol-is-it-like-git/4766398#4766398) in another question. The key point is that "replication" is simply a DB client. It connects to both couches, reads from the source, and writes to the target.

Any other big-picture architecture (peer-to-peer, multi-master, master-slave) is just the implementation of the developers or the system administrators. For example, if `GET`s are distributed to many couches, but `POST` go to one central couch which replicates to the others, that is effectively master-slave. If you put a CouchDB in every major city for performance, and they replicate directly with each other, that is multi-master replication.

Within the CouchDB community, and especially from Chris Anderson's projects and presentations, "peer-to-peer" replication is a concept where CouchDB is everywhere: mobile phones, data centers, telephone poles. And replication happens directly between couches in a decentralized way, without a central authority or architecture, like the web itself.

Comment: Yes, thank you. For now, I will stick to this "definition" but that really makes it hard to compare other DBMSes to each other regarding replication...

Comment: That is because no mainstream database compares to CouchDB regarding replication.