# Do CouchDB documents have a DAG?

Tags: couchdb, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm looking at CouchDB. Documents have versions, and you can have conflicting versions. Does it store the version sequence as a directed acyclic graph (DAG), like dvcs do? If not, how is it implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot rely on versions of documents in CouchDB, they are only kept to allow conflict resolution during replication. Previous versions of documents are deleted during [compaction](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Compaction).

The CouchDB wiki has [more details](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_revisions) on this.

Comment: Hmm - The reason I was interested in getting a DAG was I was hoping to find a lca for a conflict revision, so that a 3-way merge could be done. But If I can't rely on been access the lca, then I can't use that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the revision sequence *is* similar to a directed acyclic graph. I discussed this (at a conceptual level) in [CouchDB replication is like Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766391/what-is-the-couchdb-replication-protocol-is-it-like-git).

I like to say that CouchDB is like Git for pedagogical purposes. However there are significant differences. To name a few:

- CouchDB does not store the old *data*, just the old revision IDs
- CouchDB will ultimately truncate very long revision histories to retain performance

Thus, I am unsure if you can achieve a 3-way merge in practice because at most you will have only two revisions of the data to work with: source and target. The common ancestor will be known to exist, but its value will not.

While this may be a problem *in general* there are several "cheats" that make it not so bad in practice.

- The `validate_doc_update()` function prevents arbitrary modifications. It can even require change metadata to be stored as part of the document. (But this is an application-level solution.)
- A large class of data for a large class of applications can be 2-way merged: e.g. choose the latest timestamp; merge dissimilar phone numbers into an array of phone numbers; etc.

Obviously these are highly application-specific and are not general solutions.